# Get http code request

Tags: qt, qnetworkrequest

U use QNetworkRequest to send post request. How can I get HTTP code of request? I send some request to server, on server I can see my request, but i have to check http code which server will return to application.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`QNetworkRequest` can not be used without `QNetworkAccessManager` that's responsible for making the actual request to the web server. Each request done by `QNetworkAccessManager` instance returns `QNetworkReply` where you should look for the status code from the server. It's located inside the `QNetworkReply` instance headers.

The request is asynchronous so it can be catch when signal is triggered.

Easiest example would be:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
```

Then in the slot implementation:

```
void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *resp){
    QVariant status_code = resp->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    status_code.is_valid(){
        // Print or catch the status code
        QString status = status_code.toString(); // or status_code.toInt();
        qDebug() << status;
    }
}
```

Have a look on the official documentation. It explains all in details.

- [QNetworkRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html)
- [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html)